# setTimeout-ception alernative

Tags: javascript, animation

I wonder if we can do something more optimal than just nest setTimeout multiple time to animate a bunch of elements one after the other like this ugly thing:

```
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('div[data-order="0"]').parent().removeClass('flipped');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('div[data-order="1"]').parent().removeClass('flipped');
            setTimeout(function () {
               $('div[data-order="2"]').parent().removeClass('flipped');
            }, 75);
        }, 75);
    }, 75);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a function:

```
function flipByOrder(order) {
    $('div[data-order="' + order + '"]').parent().removeClass('flipped');
    if (order <= 1) {
        setTimeout(function() { flipByOrder(order + 1); }, 75);
    }
}
flipByOrder(0);
```

You could also use `setInterval`:

```
var order = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    $('div[data-order="' + order + '"]').parent().removeClass('flipped');
    order++;
    if (order > 2) clearInterval(interval);
}, 75);
```